# Array Not Defined in Loop?

Tags: ruby, arrays, loops

I have code like the following:

```
arra = ["a","b","c"]

arrb = ["a","e","d"]

arrc = arra - arrb

while arrc.size != 0
   somedef(arrc)
end
```

I get this error:
NameError: undefined local variable or method `arrc' for main:Object 
pointing to the line inside the while loop.  Can anyone help me understand why this is?

Comment: What do you hope `while arrc` will do?

Comment: Show the full error message and the implementation for `somedef`

Comment: `arrc,size`  is not the same as: `arrc.size` :-)

Answer (score 1):

Are you doing something like this in "somedef":

```
def somedef(a)
    p arrc
end
```

If so, you get the error because "arrc" is not a global variable. Do this instead:

```
def somedef(a)
    p a
end
```

Comment: This could be my answer.  If I turn my while loop into a def, I can put the array as a parameter, and then it will get passed properly.  Thanks!